# Maximum Of Lowest Score

Tags: combinatorics

There are **30 contestants** which have been chosen to join a **Mathematics Competition**. There are **8 essay questions**, and every one of them must solve all of the problems given.
After the competition, in order to measure the contestant's ability to solve all of that problems, the committee has decided that the score for each problem is equal to the number of students who **cannot solve** that problem

(for example, if 9 students cannot solve problem 1, then there is a maximum point 9 for problem 1. And if all contestants can solve problem 1, then there are no points can be given in that problem)

Suppose that, after their score was calculated, **Ponimin** got the **lowest score** among the others, and no other contestants got the same score as Ponimin.

Find the **maximum score** that Ponimin can get.

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: Sorry. I got this problem from my friend (middle school student) and don't know its source. I want to know it, too.

Answer (score 0):

**A rough upper bound**: Let $p$ be the number of contestants, $q$ be the number of questions and $M$ be $q\times p$ matrix where $M_{ij}=$ points obtained by $j$ th contestant for $i$ th question. If $s$ is the unique minimum score, then counting along columns and rows separately, $$s+(s+1)(p-1)\le \sum_{v=1}^{q}k_v(p-k_v)$$ where $k_v$ is the number of contestants who answered $v$ th question.

We note that product $k_v(p-k_v)\le \lfloor \frac{p}{2} \rfloor \lceil \frac{p}{2} \rceil$. Simplifying for $s$,$$s\le \lfloor  \frac{\left(q \lfloor\frac{p}{2} \rfloor \lceil \frac{p}{2} \rceil \right) + (1-p)}{p} \rfloor$$